# is there any way at all to recover css from dreamweaver?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver, recovery, disaster-recovery

I was working on a project on dreamweaver and the power went out unexpected. After the power went back on, i found my css file blank, everything was erased but the html file was intact. I'm so freaked out right now because it was a week work. I've been searching all over to recover from this issue but to no avail. So I'm trying here in case there is a genius who actually knows how to recover it maybe like in form of backup and log or whatever. Anyone please I don't wanna loose this.

Answer (score 0):

IF you saved it at least once it should have opened with a dialog about recovering, otherwise.. You are out of luck.
https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/files-folders.html

Comment: I  did  save  it  but  no dialog  showed  up  to  restore  or  recover.

Comment: What version of dreamweaver are you using?

Comment: Cs 6. It  was  so strange

Comment: You can try and see if there is a recovery folder:

Mac OS X: Users/[User Name]/Library/Cache/Adobe Dreamweaver/Version[#.0]/Dreamweaver Recovery
Windows Vista and 7: C:\Users\[User Name]\AppData\Local\Adobe\Dreamweaver\Version [#].0\en_US\Caches\Dreamweaver Recovery

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I couldn't find the Dreamweaver folder on Adobe. I've recreate it again so I'll be off with this topic. but just incase someone else have a solution which worked do post it for those who might come searching for it.